# How to pivot_longer with prefix to ID column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My data often contain either "Left/Right" or "Pre/Post" prefixes without separators in a wide format that I need to pivot to tall format combining variables by these prefixes. I have a work around of using "gsub()" to insert a separator ("_" or ".") into the column names. "pivot_longer" then does what I want with the "names_sep" argument.  I'm wondering though if there is a way to make this work more directly with "pivot_longer" "names" syntax ("names_prefix", "names_pattern", "names_to"). Here is what I am attempting:

Original wide format example:

```
HW <- tribble(
  ~Subject,  ~LeftV1,  ~RightV1, ~LeftV2, ~RightV2,  ~LeftV3, ~RightV3,
  "A", 0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101,
  "B", 2, 3, 12, 13, 102, 103,
  "C", 4, 5, 14, 15, 104, 105)
```

Desired tall format:

```
HWT <- tribble(
  ~Subject,  ~Side, ~V1,  ~V2,  ~V3,
  "A", "Left", 0, 10, 100,
  "A", "Right", 1, 11, 101, 
  "B", "Left", 2, 12, 102,
  "B", "Right", 3, 13, 103,
  "C", "Left", 4, 14, 104,
  "C", "Right", 5, 15, 105)
```

I've tried various iterations of syntax that look more or less like this:

```
HWT <- HW %>% pivot_longer(
  cols = contains(c("Left", "Right")),
  names_pattern = "/^(Left|Right)",
  names_to =  c('Side', '.value') )
```

or this:

```
HWT <- HW %>% pivot_longer(
  cols = contains(c("Left", "Right")),
  names_prefix = "/^(Left|Right)",
  names_to =  c('Side', '.value') )
```

Each of which give syntax errors that I am unsure how to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
HW %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -Subject, names_to = c("Side", ".value"),
   names_pattern = "^(Left|Right)(.*)")
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Subject Side     V1    V2    V3
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A       Left      0    10   100
2 A       Right     1    11   101
3 B       Left      2    12   102
4 B       Right     3    13   103
5 C       Left      4    14   104
6 C       Right     5    15   105
```

Comment: I agree that this will work for the example given but my actual data sets will have variables of all different names, not just starting with 'v".  My bad for not giving a better example.  So I think the key would be a regex that looks for the first character after Left or Right as a separator?

Comment: @bmacwilliams I modified to `[A-Z]` assuming the split is between a lower case and upper case

Comment: While this does split correctly on Left/Right it also truncates the column names where additional caps are included. For example "LeftVariableOne" and "RightVariableOne" become just "Variable", not "VariableOne".

Comment: @bmacwilliams In that case you can use `names_pattern` instead of `names_sep` i.e. `names_pattern = "^(Left|Right)(.*)")`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar approach concerning pivot_longer but with another strategy. I find it easier to understand if we could a simple separate like `_`. For this we could use `rename_with` and `str_replace` before pivoting:

```
librayr(dplyr)
library(stringr)

HW %>% 
  rename_with(., ~str_replace_all(., 'V', '_V')) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Subject,
               names_to =c("Side", ".value"),
               names_sep ="_")
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Subject Side     V1    V2    V3
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A       Left      0    10   100
2 A       Right     1    11   101
3 B       Left      2    12   102
4 B       Right     3    13   103
5 C       Left      4    14   104
6 C       Right     5    15   105
```

Comment: This is exactly how I currently do it, I just use gsub() instead of str_replace().